# Click on element containing text in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having trouble clicking an element from a dropdown list dynamically loaded after another click.

In the console of chrome, I am doing this by

```
$('.save-to-list-dropdown__trigger').click()
```

then

```
$( "div:contains('textcontained')" ).click()
```

However, I need this to be done by puppeteer.

I have tried

```
await page.$eval('.save-to-list-dropdown__trigger', form => form.click());
```

then

```
const linkHandlers = await page.$x("//div[contains(text(), 'textcontained')]");
```

but linkHandlers remains lenght 0.

This is the HTML of the dropdown

```
<div class="artdeco-dropdown__content-inner">
        <div id="ember169" class="ember-view"><ul role="menu" class="save-to-list-dropdown__content">
  <li role="menuitem">
<div id="ember170" class="a11y-artdeco-dropdown save-to-list-dropdown__create-new-list-button artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="plus-icon" class="save-to-list-dropdown__create-new-list-icon mr1" size="small"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M14,9H9v5H7V9H2V7H7V2H9V7h5V9Z" class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path></svg></li-icon>
      Create  list
</div>  </li>
  <li role="menuitem">
<div id="ember171" class="a11y-artdeco-dropdown artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->      My saved leads 
</div>  </li>
      <li role="menuitem">
        <h3 tabindex="-1" id="custom_lists_header_ember172" class="save-to-list-dropdown__heading display-flex">
<div id="ember173" class="save-to-list-dropdown__heading-text p0 t-sans t-black t-normal text-uppercase artdeco-dropdown__header ember-view">            Your Custom Lists:

</div>        </h3>

        <ul role="menu" class="save-to-list-dropdown__no-max-height" aria-labelledby="custom_lists_header_ember172">
              <li role="menuitem">
<div id="ember175" class="a11y-artdeco-dropdown artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->                  <div class="display-flex">
                    <div class="nowrap-ellipsis">Editors</div>
                      <div class="save-to-list-dropdown__override-small-text flex-shrink-zero" aria-label="26 leads">
                        (26)
                      </div>
                  </div>
</div>              </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<!----></ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help, I have solved it like this:

```js
const [linkHandler] = await page.$x("//div[contains(., 'textcontained')]");

if (linkHandler) {
  await linkHandler.click();
}
```

Comment: Tried this but just get: ```TypeError: page.$x is not a function```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the element's not loaded yet. You could wait for that xpath.

```js
const linkHandlers = await page.waitForXPath("//div[contains(text(), 'My saved leads')]");
```

`waitForXPath` will not only wait but return that element.

Comment: No. element is there.

Comment: Did you test that Xpath in DevTools?

Answer (score 4):

here
 is another way to do it , in this example .`item` is class of divs you can use other selectors

```
//wait for elements to appear on the page 
await page.waitForSelector('.item' , {  visible: true , timeout: 0 });

// capture all the items
let elements = await page.$$('.item');
// loop trough items
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    let  text  = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, elements[i]);
    if(text.indexOf("My saved leads") > -1 )
    {
         await elements[i].click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger a double while on the click function